# 'git show' does not pipe control characters for color

Tags: colors, git, xargs, less

I'm trying to output a list of git-show results and pipe them into a pager.
Unfortunately I'm unable to preserve color.
This is the command I'm running:
`git log -n10 | awk '{print $1}' | xargs -d '\n' -I{} bash -c 'git show {}' -- | less -MR`

Without the `| less -MR` pipe, the output is printed in color.
I've tried `less -r` as well, but obviously the problem seems to be in that `git show` or `xargs` do not preserve color when they detect that their output is being piped to another command rather than to `stdout`.

The `xargs` manual says nothing about preserving color, neither does the `git` manual.

How do I preserve color in the `less` pager output?

Comment: I actually found the solution in `man git-show` as I was half-through the question, so might as well post and mark as accepted answer for the benefit of the community..

Answer (score 2):

`man git-show` describes how to force-preserve color, seems to be taken from `man git-diff`:

```
   --color[=<when>]
       Show colored diff.  --color (i.e. without =<when>) is the same as --color=always.  <when> can be one of always, never, or auto.
```

Updated bash command:
`git log -n10 | awk '{print $1}' | xargs -d '\n' -I{} bash -c 'git show --color=always {}' -- | less -MR`